# Django-Rest-Framework File Upload

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework to upload a file
My view file looks like this:

```
class FileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Files.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FilesSerializer
    #+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = FilesSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.error, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

My view works well with file upload even if there is no bottom part of the comment.
So why should I use the code under the comment?

I used the translator.
Please understand if there is a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working without the post function because **ModelViewSet** class(i.e the one you inherited in your FileViewSet) already has implementations of various actions like list(),create(), retrieve(), update() etc.

So when you are hitting post request for uploading the file, create() action gets called automatically and will save the file by taking values provided by you in class variables like serializer_class,parser_classes etc.

Read more about [ModelViewSet](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset):